# I am unable to convert the following SQL query to .Net Entity framework

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
SELECT * 
FROM HCMTemplates 
INNER JOIN Status ON HCMTemplates.TemplateStatus=Status.Id 
INNER JOIN Country ON HCMTemplates.AssignToCountry=Country.code
Where HCMTemplates.TemplateName like '%ABC%'
```

I am unable write this query in format of Entity FrameWork

Comment: Can you please tell what you tried and where exactly you are facing issue while converting?

Comment: You have posted the SQL query but did not inform us what exact issue you are facing while converting the SQL Query to EF code. If you are receiving any error or warning then please share the screenshot of it. You could inform us how you are trying to convert it and at which step you are facing the issue? It could help us better understand the issue.

Comment: So what was the problem? Are you able to write onr for just one table?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the tables listed have relationships like

```
public class HCMTemplates
{
   //properties
   public ICollection<Status> Status {get; set;}
   public ICollection<Country> Country {get; set;}
}

public class Status
{
   //properties
   public HCMTemplates HCMTemplates {get; set;}
}

public class Country
{
   //properties
   public HCMTemplates HCMTemplates {get; set;}
}
```

you could use

```
context.HCMTemplates.Include(x => x.Status).Include(x => x.Country).Where(x => x.TemplateName.Contains("ABC")).ToList();
```

if no relationship is establish

```
 context.HCMTemplates
    .Join(
        dbContext.Status,
        hCMTemplates=> hCMTemplates.TemplateStatus,
        status=> status.Id,
        (hCMTemplates, status) => new { hCMTemplates, status}
    )
    .Join(
        dbContext.Country,
        joinedTable => joinedTable.hCMTemplates.AssignToCountry,
        country=> country.code,
        (joinedTable , country) => new { joinedTable , country}
    )
    .Where(x => x.joinedTable.hCMTemplates.TemplateName.Contains("ABC")).ToList()
```

not sure with the `Where clause`, but mostly that is the code

Answer (score 0):

The `where` statement actually doesn't really work as you would expect for entity framework. You cannot simply use a where after an include and expect it to work. Check out this article: https://entityframework.net/include-with-where-clause

Did you try this? If you did, can you show us your C# code?